# How do you change a notification action button's icon?

Tags: android, android-notifications

When you build a notification and add an action button using .addAction(int icon, CharSequence title, PendingIntent intent) is there a way to change the icon when pressed?

Answer (score 0):

To change the icon of action at realtime, you need to set new action with same title and new icon, and then restart notification.
For example:

```
notificationBuilder.actions[1] = new Notification.Action(R.drawable.pause, "play", pendingIntent);
startForeground(101, notificationBuilder);
```

or

```
notificationBuilder.actions[1] = new Notification.Action(R.drawable.pause, "play", pendingIntent);
((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(101, notificationBuilder);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the broadcast, process the button event in it (to change the icon, create a new notification with the changed icon and call it with the previous id), and pass the necessary parameters to the intent.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a drawable like below, and give it to addAction

button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/actionbarcontacts_on" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/actionbarcontacts_on" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/actionbarcontacts_off"/>
</selector>
```

`addAction(R.drawable.button, <title>, <intent>);`

Comment: How do you change the icon later on though? Specifically I want to change the action button's icon once it is pressed